# Adding VeeValidate to Vue Custom Component causes infinite update loop warning on Vue component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vee-validate

I am using VeeValidate library in my custom components which are rendered dynamically using v-for loop. I made sure that the name for each custom component is unique. But after I add v-validate attribute on the custom control it causes the below warning:

> [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render
>   function.

E.g. Below is the sample of the code:

```
<my-custom-component
     :name="someUniqueName"
     v-Model="model"
     v-validate="'myCustomValidatorRule'"
/>
```

Why is this happening and what kind of strategy can I use to get rid of this warning?

Comment: Which version of VeeValidate are you using? Can you show you `myCustomValidatorRule` code?

Comment: It turn out that my custom component key was having problem and after fixing that VeeValidate started working properly. So no issue with this rule now. Thanks.